# SBT: Cross-platform way to set java.library.path?

Tags: scala, sbt, native, java.library.path

I was working on a project that requires loading of native libraries, and so far, all development was restricted to Linux. In order to `run` my project, I could simply enable forking and modify `java.library.path` as follows:

```
javaOptions in run += "-Djava.library.path=some/common/path:lib/native/linux"
```

My question is: How can I do the same in a cross-platform way, so that I can share my build.sbt with a Windows-based developer. There are in particular three things that I couldn't figure out so far:

- I know that SBT allows to construct platform-independent paths like `"dir1" / "dir2"`, but I'm not aware of a cross-platform way to join multiple paths (since it is `:` on Linux and `;` on Windows).
- Is it possible to append either `lib/native/linux` *or* `lib/native/windows` dependent on the platform?
- My approach above overwrites `java.library.path` -- is it possible to append instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you can use any Scala code, you can of course do

```
val folderName =
  if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")) "windows" else "linux"

val libPath = Seq("some/common/path", s"lib/native/$folderName").mkString(java.io.File.pathSeparator)

javaOptions in run += s"-Djava.library.path=$libPath"
```

though this doesn't answer your last question.

Comment: This is looking good. I forgot to mention that I'm still using SBT 0.12 and, in general, I was hoping for a version agnostic solution. But I think this idea works in 0.12 as well. I still have a hard time to use SBT's `/` syntax though, since there is no implicit conversion from String to (I guess) File. But obviously there is always the work-around of doing it manually with `separatorChar`. And for debugging purposes: Any idea why `show java-options` always just returns `List()`?

Comment: Yes, this should work fine in 0.12. Except, IIRC, it uses Scala 2.9 for build configuration, so string interpolation should be replaced with `+`. For the last question, I don't know. Maybe ask it separately?

Comment: What about `System.getProperty("java.library.path")` and do the concatenation yourself?

Comment: I guess my mistake was to assume that SBT must have a nice idiomatic solution for all that (like with modifying the classpath for instance). The idea of doing this manually just felt wrong to me. But overall: Problem solved.